# DAO methods parameters , object-references vs ids

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository, dao

## Question

What is the best practice for the type of paramaters of dao/repository method, entity-objects or entity-ids?

## Example code

```
@Entity
class Product {
    // ...

    @ManyToOne
    Seller seller;
}

@Entity
class Seller {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    Long id;
}

class ProductDao {
    // ...

    // Using ids
    public List<Product> getProductsOf(long sellerId) {
        return getSession()
            .createQuery("from Product where seller.id = ?")
            .setLong(0, sellerId)
            .list();    
    }

    // Using object-references
    public List<Product> getProductsOf(Seller seller) {
        return getSession()
            .createQuery("from Product where seller = ?")
            .setEntity(0, seller)
            .list();    
    }

    // Using object-references using merge() on a detached object
    public List<Product> getProductsOf2(Seller seller) {
        Seller persistentSeller = getSession().merge(seller);

        return getSession()
            .createQuery("from Product where seller = ?")
            .setEntity(0, seller)
            .list();    
    }

    // Using object-references using lock() on a detached object
    public List<Product> getProductsOf3(Seller seller) {
        getSession().buildLockRequest(LockOptions.NONE).lock(seller);

        return getSession()
            .createQuery("from Product where seller = ?")
            .setEntity(0, seller)
            .list();    
    }
}
```

## Pros and cons

I have found the following pros and cons, but I was wondering if there is a best practice among experienced Spring/Hibernate/JPA users.

### Pros of: getProductsOf(Seller seller)

- Easy to use from a client perspective when you already have a seller that is in the persistent context (persistent state).

### Cons of: getProductsOf(Seller seller)

- You have to verify that seller is in persistent or detached state, which can make its implementation verbose. You'll have to use merge() or locking, see getProductsOf2() and getProductsOf3().
- Even if you know the id of the seller, you first have to query the seller object separatly. (load() can be used to use a proxy instead to avoid the extra query to Seller, but you still have to call the session object.)
- the parameter can be null.

### Pros of: getProductsOf(long sellerId)

- When you don't have a seller object yet, but know the sellerId, this may be faster when you only need to query for a sellerId once in the unit-of-work.
- Avoids the null reference problems

### Cons of: getProductsOf(long sellerId)

- When multiple "long" parameters exist in the method, you may mistake in the argument call order, causing you to query using wrong ids.
- Feels like a less object-oriented approach than using an object as parameter.
- The method call looks less clean:
  `getProductsOf(seller.getId())`
  instead of:
  `getProductsOf(seller)`

## My preference

I'm using `getProductsOf(Seller seller)`, but having to verify whether seller is in persistent or detached state is very cumbersome. Therefor, I'm thinking of using ids instead.

Comment: I would say it depends. If you just want an object by its id, then there's no need to create a whole object reference to set the id and pass this as parameter. On the other hand, if you need to pass several parameters, use a proper object reference.

Comment: *When multiple "long" parameters exist in the method, you may mistake in the argument call order, causing you to query using wrong ids* if this happens to you, I would say there's a problem in your design.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to avoid writing down your own DAO and use [Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) instead.

I prefer the Spring Repository API, which looks like this:

```
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>
    extends Repository<T, ID> {                                                                                                                     
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);

    T findOne(ID primaryKey);

    Iterable<T> findAll();

    Long count();

    void delete(T entity);

    boolean exists(ID primaryKey);

}
```

- the `save` and `delete` methods take an entity
- the `findOne` and `exists` take an identifier because it assumes you don't have the entity that you want to fetch

As for `findOne`, it's better to have it take an identifier. This way you can call it even if you have an entity. If it were taken an entity, then you'd have to create a transient entity with a populated identifier just for the sake of fetching the associated managed entity.

Comment: These are basic crud operations instead of operations on OneToMany/ManyToOne etc. The problem doesn't really applies to crud operations. Also, at some point, you want to write your own custom query method. In the Spring Data doc, they used: `User findByEmailAddress(EmailAddress emailAddress); `, which suggests that they prefer object references instead of ids, but emailAddress could be a value type, so its not exactly clear what the Spring developers prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have them both?

```
public List<Product> getProductsOf(long sellerId){
    return getSession()
        .createQuery("from Product where seller.id = ?")
        .setLong(0, sellerId)
        .list();
}

public List<Product> getProductsOf(Seller seller){
    return getProductsOf(seller.getId());
}
```

On a side note, I prefer to use classes instead of native types for ids because that way you can verify if the object is new (seller.getId()==null) and call either persist() or merge().